# laravel 5.4 update composer show warning PHP start up :unable to load dynamics library 'ext\php_pdo_oci.dll'

Tags: html, laravel

I try to update composer by type composer update in command prompt , it take a long time and then this happens(see picture)

PHP warning:[image]
 I don't know what wrong and how should i do?

Comment: Go to your ext directory path. i..e php/ext folder and check whether the listed dll's are exists. If not installed those modules or download those dll's and enable it from php.ini file.

Comment: Alankar   it have in this directory and i enable it in php.ini also but this problem still happed

Comment: If you are using wamp then by clicking of wamp icon all error dll's are enabled or modules are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the PDO and PDO_MYSQL extensions in your php.ini file.

On a windows server you can add the following lines in your php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

On a Linux server you can compile php with the following option --with-pdo-mysql In your php.ini, add the following lines

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Comment: it have three difference type of php.ini file such as INI-development,INI-Production file and Configuration settings Which one  should i go to enable these dll's ?